# what is parallel run length in DRC check

Tags: layout, fabrication, drc

What exactly is parallel run length in DRC check. I understand that there should be a minimum spacing between two metals depeding upon their parallel run length.

[image]

In the above figure R1 is the parallel length between polygon A and B. Should I also consider R2 between horizontal edges of ploygon 'B' as a parallel length with in the polygon ?

Please explain!

Comment: Are we talking IC DRC or PCB DRC?

Comment: When two signals run next to each other for a "long way" there is cross talk. The longer the run, the more the cross talk. If one of the signals is an "aggressor" signal, and the other is a "victim" then it may be advisable to increase the separation, or re-route one of them to avoid the parallel run.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it is IC DRC

Comment: @mkeith So we should not look for DRC with in same polygon?

Comment: Both sides are the same net so it wouldn't mean anything to have crosstalk between them.

Comment: I have never done IC design, only PCB design. So there could be issues I am not aware of. But it seems like there is no reason to be concerned about parallel length on same net.